# way to add an html element to my textarea automatically and add the counter in it

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am already using code to resize my javascript textarea,

like this

```
var tx = document.getElementsByTagName('textarea');
                    for (var i = 0; i < tx.length; i++) {
                        tx[i].setAttribute('style', 'height:' + (tx[i].scrollHeight) + 'px;overflow-y:hidden;');
                        tx[i].addEventListener("input", OnInput, false);
                }

                function OnInput(e) {
                    this.style.height = 'auto';
                    this.style.height = (this.scrollHeight) + 'px';
                }
```

i am trying to add some functionality to it, like create the span element with javascript just underneath it automatically and start counting the characters. There is no limit on entry, but just keep counting.

and if nothing is entered just showing 0 characters entered

Comment: `<textarea>` elements cannot contain other elements

Comment: Add a wrapper round the textarea and place the counter absolute inside the wrapper

Comment: i can't add any wrapper because i have tons of textareas and i want them one jquery function or js code should be able to do it, that is why i had half code here an half more added

Comment: ... You could wrap the textarea with, for example, a div by using javascript?